# Substitution to double money sign $$

Tags: math-mode

When I insert the double money sign $$ we have the equation stressed centered. I would like to know if it's possible to have a substitute for the double money sign $$. I'm looking for a symbol to get the equation stressed and written from the left side to the right side of the page instead to have the equation centered.

Thanks

Comment: You should never use `$$` in latex, the correct syntax is `\[a=b\]` then this will be flush left if you use the `fleqn` option to `\documentclass`

Comment: Are you using Plain TeX?

Comment: @egreg the original tag was latex3 so I was assuming not, It can't hurt to ask though I suppose.

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry, what is "plain TeX?"

Comment: @user26832 Then follow the advice given by David.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I do that? write \documentclass[fleqn]?

Comment: @egreg So I have just to write \[a=b\]? I did that and nothing happened.

Comment: @user26832 `\[a=b\]` with `\ ` not `[a=b]` but please read (any) basic latex tutorial.